# Can I use an async value setter in ag-Grid (TypeScript errors)?

Tags: typescript, async-await, ag-grid

I am using ag-Grid with TypeScript and trying to create an async [value setter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-setters/) in my column definition.

```ts
const columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
  {
    headerName: 'Name',
    field: 'name',
    editable: true,
    valueSetter: async (params: ValueSetterParams): Promise<boolean> => {
      return await doSomething(params); // Will return the change boolean
    }
  },
  //...other columns
```

But TypeScript complains that this signature is not supported because the `colDef.d.ts` definition file has

```ts
valueSetter?: ((params: ValueSetterParams) => boolean) | string;
```

However, if I just use `// @ts-ignore` to ignore the TypeScript error it seems to be respecting the `await` and my code executes in the right order.

Is it just an issue with the TypeScript definition file? Or does ag-Grid not support async value setters?

Some environment info:

- ag-Grid 22.1.0
- TypeScript 3.7.2
- Aurelia (which uses WebPack, npm, etc.)
- WebStorm 2019.3.1

Answer (score 7):

Ag-grid doesn't provide support for this, but you can still accomplish it. Instead of returning the promise, you still have to return a boolean. Then you have to manually refresh the cells after the promise returns:

```
valueSetter: (params: ValueSetterParams) => {
  doSomething(params).then(function() {
    params.api.refreshCells({
      rowNodes: [params.node],
      columns: [params.column]
    });
  });
  return false;
}
```

Here is an example, where I just use a `setTimeout` to emulate an async operation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-typescript-async-value-setter?file=src/main.ts