# AG-Grid async valueGetter? (always returns [object Promise])

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I'm using AG-Grid (in React, but an explanation in any framework will do) and have a custom 'valueGetter' applied to my colDef that carries out a calculation/format on the cell value before returning it to be displayed in the cell.

**Current (functions as expected):**

```
const defaultColDef = {
  valueGetter: (params) => {
    const result = doCalcFormat(params);  //doCalcFormat applies calculations and formats
    return result;
    },
 }
```

I'm trying to add the ability for the 'doCalcFormat' func to be asynchronous so that inside of it can get data from an API, then calculate/format with that data, and *then* return the final value to the valueGetter.

However, when I apply the `async` keyword to my valueGetter, all of my cells are filled with [object Promise] instead of the actual value

**Attempting:**

```
const defaultColDef = {
   valueGetter: async (params) => {             //added 'async'
    const result = await doCalcFormat(params);  //an async version of 'doCalcFormat()' was made
    console.log(result);                       //always logs expected result
    return result;
   },
}

async function doCalcFormat(params) {
    const res = await loadDataFunction();   //async func
    return res;
}
```

But when table loads:

[image]  //table fills with [object Promise]

My question is, why does this happen and how could I wait for 'doCalcFormat' to finish its operation before returning in my valueGetter? Even if I leave 'doCalcFormat' to be a normal function it still does this same thing, making me think the 'async' in valueGetter is throwing it off

Comment: From what you describe, the implementation (AG-Grid) does not allow `valueGetter` to be `async`. So the solution is to write an external async function which gets the values and, upon getting them, tells AG-Grid: here are the values, update them (synchronously).

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64294316/1891677).